# How to find closed form for $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \left(\ln(1-x) \right)^{n-1}dx$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, closed-form-expressions, polylogarithms

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447529/on-the-relationship-between-re-operatornameli-n1i-and-operatornameli/4776340#4776340) in my answer I got the real part for the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) at $1+i$ for natural $n$

$$ \Re\left(\text{Li}_n(1+i)\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n+1}A_n-B_n $$

where
$$ B_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{2\eta(2k)}{(n-2k)!}\operatorname{Re}\left[\left(\frac{\ln2}{2}-\frac{3\pi}{4}i\right)^{n-2k}\right] $$
which is easy to evaluate the closed form by using [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

But $A_n$ is defined as
$$ A_n=4 \text{Li}_n \left(\frac{-1}{4} \right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},n,\frac{1}{4}\right) $$
by using [Lerch zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function), so it has an integral representation
$$ A_n=\frac{(-4)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2+1} \left(\ln(1-x) \right)^{n-1}dx.$$
I got closed form of this integral for $n=2,3,4$: precisely
$$ 
\begin{split}
A_2 &=\frac{10\pi^2}{3}-8\ln^22,\\
A_3 &=140\zeta(3)+\frac{16}{3}\ln^32-\frac{20\pi^2}{3} \ln2\\
A_4 &=320 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{343}{90}\pi^4+\frac{32}{3}\ln^42-\frac{20\pi^2}{3}\ln^22 
\end{split}$$
**Question**: is it possible to find a closed form expression for $A_n$ for every natural $n$?

**Note**: by closed form I meant way to simplify the Lerch $\Phi$ function and use only the polylogarithm function (without complex numbers) or Clausen function, because some values of this functions are known as constants and it cant be express simply as constants just like $Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

this question asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862045/how-to-find-closed-form-for-int-01-fracxx21-left-ln1-x-rightn).

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form"? Please give the definition of "closed form"

Comment: Probably, they want to express $A_n$ in terms of $Li_k(1/2)$, $\pi$, $\ln 2$, $\zeta(k)$, where $k\le n$, or show that this is not possible.

Comment: @GHfromMO I meant to express the phi lerch function in terms of polylogarithm function

Comment: @Nemo yes... just cancle the phi lerch function

Comment: And what do you mean by "express"? A linear combination of the listed quantities, or perhaps a polynomial of them?

Comment: @GHfromMO just cancel the phi lerch function and use polylogarithm only and without complex numbers..I think it can be as we got it for $n=4$

Comment: @Faoler Note that the condition "without complex numbers" is not included in your question. The complex conjugate pairs stem from the cosine in my answer below. You might be able to rewrite $A_n$ using more and more complicated expressions with growing $n$, but what is the benefit?

Comment: because my basic problem was evaluation the real part of polylogarithm function So we must add this condition , and simply expression is better solution for $A_n$ for example it must has a closed form if n=5 I mean $2\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\Phi \left(-\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{3}{4}\right)$

Comment: It is not clear what it means "use polylogarithm only". The verb "use" is not a mathematical term. Please explain precisely what kind of answer you expect, otherwise your question is not well-defined.

Comment: @GHfromMO briefly the phi lerch function here give as a series $2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(-4)^k \left(k+\frac{1}{4} \right)^n }-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(-4)^k \left(k+\frac{3}{4} \right)^n }$ and I need to use series as form $\sum_{a=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{x^k}{k^a}$ for some values $a,N$ because its more simply expression

Comment: In your last comment, the first expression is a function of $n$, while the second expression is a function of $N$ and $x$. So there is a mismatch of variables.

Comment: @GHfromMO we need to find the variables $N,x$ if we know $n$

Comment: OK. So what are $N,x$ for $n=4$?

Comment: @GHfromMO ok I think its complicate finding here we can see it used $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{320}{2^k k^4}$ with $\zeta(4)$ and other constants anyway I just gave you an example for what I mean by closed form So maybe there are another expression which is similar ..if there is not just explain why.

Answer (score 8):

I’m not sure if this is what the OP wants, but…

Mathematica can integrate the indefinite integral for positive integer $n$. Inserting the upper limit $x=1$ gives zero for $n \in \mathbb N$, while the lower limit $x=0$ can be evaluated, leading to the "closed form"
$$\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
A_n = 2^{2n+1} \left[
\operatorname{Li}_n \left(\tfrac{1+i}{2} \right)+
\operatorname{Li}_n \left(\tfrac{1-i}{2} \right) \right] \,.
$$
Note the relation to the [Clausen function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html), see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function). Note also that
$$\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
A_n = 2^{2n+2} \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{
 \cos \left( \tfrac{\pi k}{4}\right)}{2^{k/2} k^{n}}\,.
$$
Sums over sine or cosine often lead to these conjugate sums, or real/imaginary parts, when expressed via the polylogarithm. The Clausen family of functions avoid these constructs.

**Edit**

The detour via indefinite integrals war not necessary, Mathematica can directly evaluate the definite integral for $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I am not understanding "Inserting the upper bound =1 gives zero in all cases". (If you're talking about a definite integral, what is the lower bound?) And what "cases" are you referring to?

Comment: @DanielAsimov: I have clarified the answer, I mixed up "bound" and "limit".

Comment: using complex numbers for $A_n$ does not solve the problem because as you see I need that to get result of $\Re(Li_n(1+i))$ and for using Clausen function we must to delete the $\sqrt{2}^{-k}$ to get a simplest result.